# How to get rid of the certificate warning to add exception when redirecting to https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

My SSL Certificate is a wild card certificate in the form of *.gotraiteur.ca. So I implemented a .htaccess redirect to force everything to go to https://www.gotraiteur.ca.

I got a security warning prompt asking to leave the website or to add an exception an continue.

After adding the exception, I get in whitout problem. When clikig on the lock in the address bar, the identity of the website is verified mention and the lock is green in Google Chrome.

This make me assume that my .htaccess redirection is setup properly and the ssl should have been installed properly on the hosting account.

The website is hosted by Pagoda Box.  Here is the .htaccess code just in case.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|img|themes|sparks|assets|promo|phase0|error_log|robots\.txt|pinterest-d797d\.html|license\.txt|Boxfile|tools)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R]
```

It's affecting the access to the website for all devices.  The bounce rate is very high.

How can I fix this issue?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with apache but it seems your redirections are fine.

On the other hand see there're some issues with your SSL configuration. Namely, I get warnings when trying to open your site from my phone.

There are several tools which help you debug issues with your certificates, I use [this one](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=gotraiteur.ca).

Run it against your site and you'll see the following warning:

> The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate. Learn more about this error. You can fix this by following GeoTrust's Certificate Installation Instructions for your server platform (use these instructions for RapidSSL). Pay attention to the parts about Intermediate certificates.

Which means your installation is missing the [intermediate certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_certificate_authorities) (basically a way for the client's browser to follow the authorization chain up to a trusted authority).

On that site you'll also find links to your provider's documentation, pay attention to [this link](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=AR1549&actp=LIST&viewlocale=en_US) which explains how to install the certificates for several web servers [including Apache](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO16223).

You'll basically have to download the intermediate certificate and configure it with apache's `SSLCACertificateFile` directive.

Follow those instructions, reload your server's configuration and rerun the tool from the first link against your site and you shouldn't see warnings anymore :)

Comment: Thx kirbuchi.  Your explanation make sense.  I will forward the information to the host and keep you posted.

Comment: Problem is  resolved.  I figured out how to put the intermediate certificate.  it's working now.  Thank you for bringing that to my attention.